# Is it possible to send window messages to an embedded website?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe

I'm creating a script that runs on every website (using temperMonkey). On a shortcut I inject a form into the page. So if I am in stackoveflow, I pres `cmd`+`esc` and I embed a local vuejs page

**Step 1: Inject an iframe to (say) stack overflow** and send a message to the embedded site**

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.type="text/html"
  iframe.src="http://localhost:8080/webhighlights"
  iframe.id="localFrame"
var data = {title: document.title,   url: window.location,}
  iframe.onload= function(){
      var t = document.getElementById('localFrame'); 
    t.contentWindow.postMessage({
        data
    }, 'http://localhost:8080/webhighlights');
  }
```

**Step 2: get the message from the site that has embedded me:**

```
mounted: function () {
/* eslint-disable */
    window.top.addEventListener('message',receiveMessage, false);
      function receiveMessage (event) {
        console.log('event data: ', event)
      }
}
```

The message doesn't come through. The error I get in the console is `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Location object could not be cloned.    at HTMLIFrameElement.iframe.onload`

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @epascarello How to do that, it does not work.

Comment: What does not work? You gave three code samples without any context text to say what the issue is.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, I've edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a message to your iframe's context, so from this iframe you don't want to listen for `top`'s messages, but only for this iframe's `window` ones.

Change

```
window.top.addEventListener('message',...
```

to

```
window.addEventListener('message',...
```

If you want to understand better how messaging works, I invite you to read [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201120/using-messagechannel-bidirectionally-for-multiple-messages-between-page-and-if/51202221#51202221).
Baiscally with an iframe, one port is in the main context, under `HTMLIframeElement.contentWindow`, and the other one is in the iframe's context, under `window`. To communicate between both contexts, each context should listen to and talk in their own port.

---

When this is fixed you will face a new issue that the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/) object can't be cloned. Since apparently you only want to send the current URL of the main page, then only send this:

```
var data = {title: document.title,   url: window.location.href };
```

Comment: Same issue, I get the error of `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Location object could not be cloned.    at HTMLIFrameElement.iframe.onload`

Comment: So different problem. This error is quite clear though, you can't post `window.location` object entirely, what did you want to send excatly? The URL? then send `location.href`.